# After binding the data to grid, sorting arrow disappears, column headers look like they're disabled

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This might be a a very basic question...but couldn't find the answer.

I am using VB.NET for developing my windows application. I am binding the collection to Datagridview. I have added just one column and am trying to sort it.  Before the binding, the data grid view looks like the image below.

[image]

In above image, we can see the arrow and the * in the grid...

After I bind the data it simply disappears so I am unable to sort any column as in the the image below.

[image]

Here is the code...

```
 Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            gvBatchList.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            Dim oBatchCollection As New Batches
            oBatchCollection.LoadOngoingBatches(True)
            gvBatchList.DataSource = oBatchCollection
            lblBatchCount.Text = "Batches (" + oBatchCollection.Count().ToString + ")"
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
            MessageBox.Show("Error :- " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

Comment: Give us some code you wrote

Comment: @user1650894 have you tried setting the `DataGridViewColumnSortMode` after you set the `DataSource.` Try setting this after you bind(datasource): **DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic** for that column.

Comment: It will be nice if you give me some example of it...

Answer (score 0):

After binding the source to the datagridview, set the sort mode for the columns that you want to be sortable.

Here is an example:

```
    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In myGrid.Columns
        col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    Next
```

The options are Not Sortable, Automatic, and Programmatic.  Automatic will allow sorting by standard means, while Programmatic will allow you to specify the behavior when sorting.  Try automatic and if it doesn't behave the way you want, do programmatic.

Here is my example of my sorting method:

```
Private Sub myGrid_Sorting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    If myGrid.SortedColumn IsNot Nothing Then
        'If a different sort column, sort ascending and change previously sorted column to none
        If e.ColumnIndex <> myGrid.SortedColumn.Index Then
            For col = 0 To myGrid.Columns.Count - 1
                myGrid.Columns(col).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None
            Next
            myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending
            myGrid.Sort(myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        Else  'otherwise toggle the direction of the sort
            If myGrid.SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
                myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending
                myGrid.Sort(myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex), ListSortDirection.Descending)
            Else
                myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending
                myGrid.Sort(myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            End If
        End If
    Else  'if grid is not already sorted, simply sort by selected column in ascending order
        myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending
        myGrid.Sort(myGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    End If

    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try it , but in which event above code (For Each loop... Code) should I write ?

Comment: @user1650894 - the loop in which you set the sort mode goes in the same event in which you bind the data source to the datagridview...just sometime after binding the source.